# Dim light Android system bars

Tags: android

I have an Activity with both status bar and navigation bar white.

With the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` I can make the status bar icons grey but when I put the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` to dim them, they become unreadable.

Is it possible to dim the system bars but keep them visibible in a light background?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, just need to use the or operator. In Kotlin:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = 
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are deprecated in 2022)

```
activity?.window?.decorView?.apply {
                        systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    }
```

One more way to dimm color of statusbar:

```
override fun setupInOnCreateView(view: View) {
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(b.draggableBottomSheetLayout)
    bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object :
        BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            when (newState) {
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> {
                    activity?.window?.apply {
                        statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black_tr_50)
                    }
                }
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> {
                    activity?.window?.apply {
                        statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black_tr_50)
                    }
                }
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> {
                    activity?.window?.apply {
                        statusBarColor = statusBarColorSaved
                    }
                    presenter.onBackPressed()
                }
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING,
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED,
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> {
                }
                else -> {
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        }

    })
```